# Installation does not setup service in Ubuntu 21.04

Tags: structr

```
~/Downloads$ sudo dpkg -i structr-3.6.4.deb 

Vorbereitung zum Entpacken von structr-3.6.4.deb ...

Entpacken von structr (3.6.4) über (3.6.4) ...

structr (3.6.4) wird eingerichtet ...

~/Downloads$ sudo service structr start

Failed to start structr.service: Unit structr.service not found.
```

Anyone from the structr team has an idea or some hints concerning local structr installation?
(Neo4j already running on the server)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can confirm that this is a problem with the 3.6.4 release. In our current 4.0 development branch this was fixed by adding a postinst script to the deb file. (See commit https://github.com/structr/structr/commit/fd3d955e9c2413d2cc3f5c81762cda95da8d5f37)

You can simply issue the command `systemctl enable structr` to enable the service at every s